# React-select clears the value (state) of the other input fields when select option is changed (onChange)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-select

I used React-select for my select on a form, when I click on select and the value of select is changed, the current state/value of the other fields input fields is cleared and onSubmit i only get the value of the selection

```
   const [values, setValues] = useState({
   username: "",
   email: "",
   time: "",
});

const handleChange = (event) => {
   setValues({
       ...values,
       [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
   });
   console.log(`Option entered:`, values);
};

const optionsTime = [
   {
       value: "15",
       label: "15 mins",
   },
   {
       value: "30",
       label: "30 mins",
   },
   {
       value: "45",
       label: "45 mins",
   },
   {
       value: "60",
       label: "60 mins",
   },
   {
       value: "75",
       label: "75 mins",
   },
];

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(`Option submited:`, values);
   alert("You are submitting " + values);
};
const handleTime = (e) => {
   //I used created a different onChange function for react-select and used e.value because react select //throws error of undefined id or value when e.target.value is used...
   if (values.time !== e.value) {
       setValues({ time: e.value });
   }

   console.log(`Option selected:`, e, values);
};
return (
   <div className="headerRow">
       <Navbar />
       <div className="col-lg-4 schedule-area d-none d-lg-block">
           <form id="schedule" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
               <h3>Schedule A Brief</h3>
               <div className="form-group">
                   <input
                       id="username"
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Contact Person"
                       className="form-control"
                       onChange={handleChange}
                       value={values.username}
                       required
                   />
               </div>
               <div className="form-group">
                   <input
                       id="email"
                       type="email"
                       placeholder="Email Address"
                       className="form-control"
                       onChange={handleChange}
                       value={values.email}
                       required
                   />
               </div>
               <div className="form-group">
                   <Select
                       id="time"
                       type="options"
                       placeholder="Select Brief Time Projection"
                       onChange={handleTime}
                       options={optionsTime}
                       valueInput={values.time}
                       isSearchable
                       required
                   />
               </div>
               <div onClick={handleSubmit} className="book_btn text-center">
                   Schedule a Brief
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
);
```

Please what can I do to get the values of all my input fields including the select field onSubmit

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are returning only **time** overriding the other old value in a **values** state

Replace

```
 const handleTime = (e) => {
     if (values.time !== e.value) {
       setValues({ time: e.value });
   }
```

To

```
const handleTime = (e) => {
 if (values.time !== e.value) {
      setValues((old)=>({...old, time: e.value })); }
```

Comment: thank you,  took a lead from your reply, gave me error but what works for me is posted below. thanks

Comment: This is a functional way of setting  value which is preferrable as it guarantee that you are receiving latest value . It should have worked. What error does it throw?

Comment: here: (declaration or statement expected)  Line 98:28:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   const handleTime = (e) => {
       if (values.time !== e.value) {
>  setValues((old)=>{...old, time: e.value });
      }

Comment: Oh i had missed paranthesis. I suggest you to go with this functional way as it guarantee you to give latest updated state. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
const handleTime = (e) => {
     if (values.time !== e.value) {
       setValues({ time: e.value });
   }
```

To:

```
const handleTime = (e) => {
    if (values.time !== e.value) {
      setValues({
        ...values,
        time: e.value
      });
    }
```

It updtates now...